# Backbone: Uncaught Type Error: .. is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I am learning Backbone and JavaScript. I am stuck at one error and this error might be related to pure JavaScript and not Backbone.

While going through tutorial of Backbone (does not uses requireJS), I found below line of code.

```
 var FirstSubViewModel = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
    var source = $("#vehicleTemplate").html();
    var template = _.template(source);

    this.$el.html(template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.$el.attr("data-color", this.model.get("color"));

    return this;
},
  });
```

We can clearly see that code `returns this`, and everything works fine.

Now I am trying to do the same in my own code base (I have used require.JS.

My view Model: **With Error: Not Working**

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
  var FirstSubViewModel = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#myChart-template').html()),
    render: function() {
      $(this.el).html(this.template());
      var ctx = $(this.el).find('#lineChart')[0];
        return this; 
},
    initialize: function() {
      this.render();
    }
  });
});
```

My Controller:

```
define(['backbone', 'FirstSubViewModel'], function(Backbone, FirstSubViewModel)
{   var ch = new dashboardModel.chart({});
        new FirstSubViewModel({
                ^^ HERE I GET ERROR
        el: '#chartAnchor1',
          model: ch
        });
});
```

My view Model: **Working Totally Fine**

```
    define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
      var FirstSubViewModel = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#myChart-template').html()),
        render: function() {
          $(this.el).html(this.template());
          var ctx = $(this.el).find('#lineChart')[0];
           // return this; Commented Out!**
    },
        initialize: function() {
          this.render();
        }
      });
return FirstSubViewModel;
    });
```

Everything works fine if I use `return FirstSubViewModel` at the bottom rather than having return this in the render function . But I want to try `return this` in the `render function` and want everything to work. I don't want to do `return FirstSubViewModel` in the end.

Error when used "return this" in the render function:

`FirstSubViewModel` is not a constructor

Comment: I have changed the sample code. I had tweaked the tutorial code while posting question. I have put the actual tutorial code now. My apologies for the confusion. And the code that you are telling is very bad is my actual code that I have written. And code given is just the snippet. I had thought this would be enough to get the issue.

Comment: So basically in tutorial the tutor uses "return this" in the render function. But I need to return the whole class at the bottom of the code. I am learning all of this stuff so I might not be doing the best practice. Kindly guide me why the issue is coming.

Comment: I also want to use "return this" in my render function but I get error. But when I return the whole class at the bottom of the code snippet everything works fine.

Comment: My sincere apologies for not asking question correctly. I have edited the question and removed extraneous code. Let me know if still the question is  not clear. And thanks a ton!

Comment: Why negative votes. If someone gives negative vote w/o explaining the reason. They should be barred from SO! Period!

Comment: I have put the code. Explained the problem and even edited my question accordingly to make it more crystal clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last return defines what will be included in other modules and in this case is required. Without this this module return `undefined`.

Lets try in console:

```
x = undefined
new x()
```

> TypeError: x is not a constructor

`return FirstSubViewModel` is mandatory. `return this` in render function is recommended.

Code:

```
define(['backbone'], function (Backbone) {
    var FirstSubViewModel = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#myChart-template').html()),
        render: function () {
            console.log("inside first sub view render");
            $(this.el).html(this.template());
            var ctx = $(this.el).find('#lineChart')[0];
            return this;

        },
        initialize: function () {
            this.render();
        }
    });

    return FirstSubViewModel; // Works as expected.
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You did not get the question right. I have edited my question. Can you kindly see it once. Many Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the answer

Comment: So I need to have both. "return this" in render function and "return FirstSubVIewModel" at the bottom?? Currently, I just have "return FirstSubVIewModel" and still everything works. Please guide me.

Comment: `return FirstSubViewModel` is mandatory. `return this` in render is recommended.

Comment: Why have you used both in your code. 1. return this. 2. return FirstSubViewModel. So basically both are required for proper functioning of the code. Even though for me the code works with just keeping "return FirstSubVIewModel" in the bottom. But its not the right way I should have both the return statement in place ideally. is that what you want to convey?

Comment: Kindly put your above comment "return FirstSubViewModel is mandatory. return this in render is recommended"  as the answer. Because that is what my actual doubt was.

Comment: Tutorial that I watched  did not use "RequireJs" and also tutor only used "return this" in the render function and never used "return FirstSubViewModel". And still his code worked. So I am guessing that when I use RequireJS. I need to apply the "return FirstSubVIewModel" at the bottom. Correct me If I am wrong. I am beginner so I get these doubts.

Comment: `return FirstSubViewModel` defines what will be included in other modules. Without this this module return `undefined`. Read this http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#amd